# UIAutomation disconnects with ADB wile running the test caese in Loop

Tags: android-uiautomator, android-instrumentation, android-usb

I am getting problem of UiAutomation Not Connected, while running the UiAutomation test cases in loop.

> AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0 AndroidRuntime: Process:
>   com.android.imstressautomation, PID: 13697 AndroidRuntime:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: UiAutomation not connected!
>   AndroidRuntime:
>   android.app.UiAutomation.throwIfNotConnectedLocked(UiAutomation.java:971)
>   AndroidRuntime:
>   android.app.UiAutomation.waitForIdle(UiAutomation.java:577)
>   AndroidRuntime:android.support.test.uiautomator.UiAutomatorBridge.waitForIdle(UiAutomatorBridge.java:112)
>   AndroidRuntime:android.support.test.uiautomator.UiAutomatorBridge.waitForIdle(UiAutomatorBridge.java:107)
>
> AndroidRuntime: at
>   android.support.test.uiautomator.QueryController.findAccessibilityNodeInfo(QueryController.java:143)
>   AndroidRuntime: at
>   android.support.test.uiautomator.QueryController.findAccessibilityNodeInfo(QueryController.java:138)
>   AndroidRuntime: at
>   android.support.test.uiautomator.UiObject.findAccessibilityNodeInfo(UiObject.java:188)
>   AndroidRuntime: at
>   android.support.test.uiautomator.UiObject.getChildCount(UiObject.java:1

Comment: Is this coming every time ? Is `adb shell` coming out of the shell when the problem occurs? As a work around, you can do `adb kill-server;adb start-server`.

Comment: It is coming randomly when i am running the UiAutomator in a loop then some times after 2 hours of test execution it coming and sometimes after 3-4 hours. It is because of the following code while connect  synchronized (mLock) {
            throwIfConnectedLocked();
            if (mIsConnecting) {
                return;
            }
            mIsConnecting = true;
        }